# Silverlight Child Window hangs the webapp at second run

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, freeze, childwindow

Following is the code I used to call the child window:

```
Dim c As New New_Contact()
                c.Title = "New Contact Details"
                AddHandler c.Closed, AddressOf NewContactClosed
                c.Show()
```

Following is the XAML for the child window:

```
<controls:ChildWindow xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"  x:Class="AtomHelpers.New_Contact"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
       Width="662" Height="363"
       Title="Add New Contact" FontSize="14">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2" Height="320">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <sdk:Label Content="Name" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,12,0,0" Name="Label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="14"/>
        <sdk:Label Content="Type" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,43,0,0" Name="Label6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="14" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Reference" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,128,0,0" Name="Label7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" FontSize="14" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Department" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,160,0,0" Name="Label8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" FontSize="14"/>
        <sdk:Label Content="Office" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,190,0,0" Name="Label9" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="14" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Profession" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,215,0,0" Name="Label10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="14" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Birthdate" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,248,0,0" Name="Label11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="14" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Primary Address" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="302,11,0,0" Name="Label12" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" FontSize="14" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Primary Numbers" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="302,131,0,0" Name="Label13" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" FontSize="14" />
        <sdk:Label Content="Allow Group" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="305,248,0,0" Name="Label14" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="14" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,8,0,0" Name="Namee" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="163" MaxLength="10" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,156,0,0" Name="Department" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" TabIndex="4" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,186,0,0" Name="Office" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" TabIndex="5" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,215,0,0" Name="Profession" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" TabIndex="6" />
        <sdk:DatePicker Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,244,0,0" Name="DatePicker1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" TabIndex="7" />
        <TextBlock Height="114" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="432,12,0,0" Name="AddressTextBlock" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <TextBlock Height="114" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="432,131,0,0" Name="NumberTextBlock" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <CheckBox  Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="405,244,0,0" Name="GroupCheckBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="10" />
        <Button Content="E" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="264,7,0,0" Name="NameButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" TabIndex="0" />
        <ScrollViewer Height="69" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="163" TabIndex="1">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button Content="E" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="264,39,0,0" Name="Typebutton2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" TabIndex="2" />
        <Button Content="E" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="608,11,0,0" Name="AddressButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" TabIndex="8" />
        <Button Content="E" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="608,127,0,0" Name="NumberButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" TabIndex="9" />
        <CheckBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,130,0,0" Name="ReferenceCheckBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Yes" TabIndex="3" FontSize="14"/>
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="141,126,0,0" Name="ComboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143" IsEnabled="False" TabIndex="3">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2,0,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Namee}" Tag="{Binding Key}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button x:Name="SaveOKButton" Content="Save" Width="75" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="226,288,0,0" TabIndex="11" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Width="75" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="319,288,0,0" TabIndex="12" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Following is the back end code for child window:

```
Partial Public Class New_Contact
Inherits ChildWindow
Dim contactObj As ContactObjs.Contact
Dim org As ContactObjs.Contact
Structure ComboItem
    Private id As String
    Private display As String
    Property Key
        Get
            Return id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Namee
        Get
            Return display
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            display = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Structure

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    contactObj = New ContactObjs.Contact
    Dim serv As New WCFContactService.ContactsClient
    AddHandler serv.GetTypesListCompleted, AddressOf TypeslistReceived
    AddHandler serv.GetGroupingContactsCompleted, AddressOf ReferenceReceived
    serv.GetTypesListAsync(App.Current.Resources("ClientID"), "Contacts Type")
    serv.GetGroupingContactsAsync(App.Current.Resources("ClientID"))
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal contactID As String)
    InitializeComponent()
    'contactObj = New ContactObjs.Contact(contactID)
    Dim serv As New WCFContactService.ContactsClient
    AddHandler serv.GetTypesListCompleted, AddressOf TypeslistReceived
    AddHandler serv.GetFullContactCompleted, AddressOf ContactReceived
    AddHandler serv.GetGroupingContactsCompleted, AddressOf ReferenceReceived
    serv.GetTypesListAsync(App.Current.Resources("ClientID"), "Contacts Type")
    serv.GetGroupingContactsAsync(App.Current.Resources("ClientID"))
    serv.GetFullContactAsync(contactID)
    SaveOKButton.Content = "Update"
End Sub

Private Sub ReferenceReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WCFContactService.GetGroupingContactsCompletedEventArgs)
    'Throw New NotImplementedException
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim result As New List(Of ComboItem)
    For Each k As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In e.Result
        Dim c As New ComboItem
        c.Key = k.Key
        c.Namee = k.Value.ToString()
        result.Add(c)
    Next
    ComboBox1.ItemsSource = result
End Sub

Private Sub AssignValues()
    Namee.Text = contactObj.Inf.Namee.ToString()

    'Reference
    If contactObj.Inf.Referenece = "" Then
        ReferenceCheckBox.IsChecked = False
    Else
        ReferenceCheckBox.IsChecked = True
        For i = 0 To ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1
            Dim c As ComboItem
            c = ComboBox1.Items(i)
            If c.Key = contactObj.Inf.Referenece Then
                ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = i
            End If
        Next
        'ComboBox1.SelectedValue = contactObj.Inf.Referenece
    End If

    Department.Text = contactObj.Inf.Department
    Office.Text = contactObj.Inf.Office
    Profession.Text = contactObj.Inf.Profession
    Try
        DatePicker1.SelectedDate = contactObj.Inf.Birthdate
    Catch ex As Exception
        DatePicker1.SelectedDate = Nothing
    End Try
    GroupCheckBox.IsChecked = contactObj.Inf.Group
    If Not contactObj.Inf.PrimaryAddressKey = "" Then
        AddressTextBlock.Text = contactObj.Inf.Addresses(contactObj.Inf.PrimaryAddressKey).ToString()
    End If
    If Not contactObj.Inf.PrimaryNumberKey = "" Then
        NumberTextBlock.Text = contactObj.Inf.Numbers(contactObj.Inf.PrimaryNumberKey).ToString()
    End If

    'Types
    If Not contactObj.Inf.ContactType = "" Then
        Dim l As New List(Of String)
        Dim t As String = ""
        For Each k As Char In contactObj.Inf.ContactType
            If k = "," Then
                l.Add(t)
                t = ""
            Else
                t = t + k.ToString()
            End If
        Next

        Dim tc As New List(Of CheckBox)
        For Each c As CheckBox In stackPanel1.Children
            If l.Contains(c.Content.ToString()) Then
                c.IsChecked = True
            End If
            tc.Add(c)
        Next
        stackPanel1.Children.Clear()
        For Each k As CheckBox In tc
            stackPanel1.Children.Add(k)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles CancelButton.Click
    Me.DialogResult = False
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub NameButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles NameButton1.Click
    Dim c As New FullName()
    If Not contactObj.Inf.Namee.ToString() = "" Then
        c = New FullName(contactObj.Inf.Namee)
    End If
    AddHandler c.Closed, AddressOf FullNameFormClosed
    c.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub FullNameFormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Throw New NotImplementedException
    Dim k As New FullName
    k = sender
    With contactObj.Inf.Namee
        .Title = k.namee.Title
        .FirstName = k.namee.FirstName
        .MiddleName = k.namee.MiddleName
        .LastName = k.namee.LastName
        .Suffic = k.namee.Suffic
        Namee.Text = contactObj.Inf.Namee.ToString()
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Typebutton2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Typebutton2.Click
    Dim c As New Types()
    AddHandler c.Closed, AddressOf TypesFormClosed
    c.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub TypesFormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Throw New NotImplementedException
    Dim c As Types = sender
    If c.DialogResult = True Then
        Dim t As New CheckBox
        t.Content = c.TextBox1.Text
        t.IsChecked = True
        stackPanel1.Children.Add(t)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TypeslistReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WCFContactService.GetTypesListCompletedEventArgs)
    'Throw New NotImplementedException
    stackPanel1.Children.Clear()
    If Not e.Result.Count = 0 Then
        For Each k As String In e.Result
            Dim c As New CheckBox
            c.Content = k
            c.IsChecked = False
            stackPanel1.Children.Add(c)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddressButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles AddressButton.Click
    If contactObj.Inf.Addresses.Count = 0 Then
        Dim c As New Addresses(contactObj.Inf.ID)
        AddHandler c.Closed, AddressOf AddressFormClosed
        c.Show()
    Else
        Dim c As New Addresses(contactObj.Inf.ID, contactObj.Inf.Addresses)
        AddHandler c.Closed, AddressOf AddressFormClosed
        c.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddressFormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Throw New NotImplementedException
    AddressTextBlock.Text = ""
    Dim c As New Addresses("")
    c = sender
    If c.DialogResult = True Then
        contactObj.Inf.Addresses = c.addr
        For Each t As ContactObjs.Address In contactObj.Inf.Addresses.Values
            If t.PrimaryAddress = True Then
                AddressTextBlock.Text = t.ToString()
                contactObj.Inf.PrimaryAddressKey = t.AddressID
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NumberButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles NumberButton.Click
    If contactObj.Inf.Numbers.Count = 0 Then
        Dim c As New Numbers(contactObj.Inf.ID)
        AddHandler c.Closed, AddressOf NumbersFormClosed
        c.Show()
    Else
        Dim c As New Numbers(contactObj.Inf.ID, contactObj.Inf.Numbers)
        AddHandler c.Closed, AddressOf NumbersFormClosed
        c.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NumbersFormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Throw New NotImplementedException
    NumberTextBlock.Text = ""
    Dim c As New Numbers("")
    c = sender
    If c.DialogResult = True Then
        contactObj.Inf.Numbers = c.num
        For Each t As ContactObjs.Number In contactObj.Inf.Numbers.Values
            If t.PrimaryNumber = True Then
                NumberTextBlock.Text = t.ToString()
                contactObj.Inf.PrimaryNumberKey = t.NumberID
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ReferenceCheckBox_Checked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles ReferenceCheckBox.Checked
    If ReferenceCheckBox.IsChecked = True Then
        ComboBox1.IsEnabled = True
    Else
        ComboBox1.IsEnabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SaveOKButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles SaveOKButton.Click
    Select Case SaveOKButton.Content
        Case "Save" 'Contact
            contactObj.Inf.ContactType = ""
            For Each k As CheckBox In stackPanel1.Children
                If k.IsChecked = True Then
                    contactObj.Inf.ContactType = contactObj.Inf.ContactType + "," + k.Content + ","
                End If
            Next
            If ReferenceCheckBox.IsChecked = True Then
                Try
                    Dim c As New ComboItem
                    c = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
                    contactObj.Inf.Referenece = c.Key
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
            Else
                contactObj.Inf.Referenece = ""
            End If
            'dept, offi, profe
            With contactObj.Inf
                .Department = Department.Text
                .Office = Office.Text
                .Profession = Profession.Text
                If IsNothing(DatePicker1.SelectedDate) = False Then
                    .Birthdate = DatePicker1.SelectedDate
                End If
                .Group = GroupCheckBox.IsChecked
            End With
            contactObj.Save()
            DialogResult = True
        Case "Update"
            contactObj.Inf.ContactType = ""
            For Each k As CheckBox In stackPanel1.Children
                If k.IsChecked = True Then
                    contactObj.Inf.ContactType = contactObj.Inf.ContactType + "," + k.Content + ","
                End If
            Next
            If ReferenceCheckBox.IsChecked = True Then
                Try
                    Dim c As New ComboItem
                    c = ComboBox1.SelectedItem
                    contactObj.Inf.Referenece = c.Key
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
            Else
                contactObj.Inf.Referenece = ""
            End If
            'dept, offi, profe
            With contactObj.Inf
                .Department = Department.Text
                .Office = Office.Text
                .Profession = Profession.Text
                If IsNothing(DatePicker1.SelectedDate) = False Then
                    .Birthdate = DatePicker1.SelectedDate
                Else
                    .Birthdate = Nothing
                End If
                .Group = GroupCheckBox.IsChecked
            End With
            contactObj.Update(org)
            DialogResult = True
    End Select
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ChildWindow_KeyUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp
    If e.Key = Key.Enter Then
        SaveOKButton_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ContactReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WCFContactService.GetFullContactCompletedEventArgs)
    'Throw(New NotImplementedException)
    If IsNothing(e.Error) Then
        contactObj = New ContactObjs.Contact(e.Result)
        AssignValues()
        org = New ContactObjs.Contact(e.Result)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Error Retreving data, please try again.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK)
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

First time and second time the child window operates flawlessly, but after closing the second time, the app gets stopped without any error.  Could you please tell me where I went wrong, I am stuck here from days together.

I really need to thank @xscape for providing me a solution for the problem, it is working like a charm now.  However, I would like to update the source code so that I could know what mistake I have  performed earlier to cause it disabled.
Files are at : [enter link description here](http://rapidshare.com/files/447177826/AtomHelpers-Backup-10.2.11.rar)

Also, I am happy that I got the solution in a matter of hrs here. which is nothing compared to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A temporary solution that seems to work is to add this code to your childwindow class.

```
Private Sub Window_Closed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed

   Application.Current.RootVisual.SetValue(Control.IsEnabledProperty, True)
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

For those newer people that google and run into this problem, silverlight 5 seems to have fixed this bug, so if you can, update to the newest release.